# How to use CloudKit in order to share different types of data between multiple apps?

Tags: containers, cloudkit

Is it possible to use any identifier for `CloudKit` containers?

I have three apps:

- App1
- App2
- App3

I would like App1 and App2 to share data from one container and App1, App2 and App3 to share data from another container.

I imagine that I should use containers with custom identifiers (via 
`+ containerWithIdentifier:`) and not use `+ defaultContainer`. I should also register the identifiers in the app's entitlement. I guess also these identifiers should be unique.

I just want to know if this is ok and if not to have more information or advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a group of three apps that share a single iCloud container. This allows all three apps to read/write the same set of data via CloudKit.

In Xcode, under the iCloud portion of the Capabilities tab, select the "Specify custom containers" and add an appropriate name. Use the same for all three apps.

Then in your code, do as you mention. Use `CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:` and pass the identifier you gave in Xcode.

This is documented under the [Share Containers Between Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH2-SW8) section of the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH1-SW1).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, create two containers.